# What are the open source alternatives to Lattix?

Tags: architecture, dependencies, lattix

I have gotten the opportunity to work with [Lattix](http://www.lattix.com/) in the past.  I believe the paradigm it represents (a hierarchical dependency matrix) is the future of large-scale system architecture management.

However the companies I work for are always put off by the price tag.  Is anyone aware of any good open-source alternatives that exist?  After much searching I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some open source tools that implement the core functionality of Lattix, DSM (Design or Dependency Structure Matrix) listed here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Structure_Matrix

The recent release of [dtangler](https://support.requeste.com/dtangler/about_dtangler) 2.0 has an something in its release notes you might find interesting:

> dtangler 2.0.0. is released! The major new feature is the ability to read dependency information from a plaintext file. In other words: it's not just for java - now you can generate a dependency structure matrix that describes whatever you want!

Comment: It's been a while, and the list of open source tools has since been removed from that page, but this is what it looked like way back then: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Design_structure_matrix&oldid=326390314

This list is probably more useful now though: https://dsmsuite.github.io/dsm_tools.html

Answer (score 2):

You could try the open source tooling at https://dsmsuite.github.io/. I developed the DSM tooling because I like the DSM approach, but hardly any open source tooling was available. It supports C/C++ (based on file includes) Java and .net (both based on import binaries)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a free tool (299 euros for a personnal license) but the tool NDepend comes with a [Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) coupled with a [Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

Here are some screenshots:

[image: NDepend Dependency Matrix]

[image: NDepend Dependency Matrix]

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube has a free dependency analyzer (in my experience, less useful than Lattix). You can add the `Package Design` widget to the dashboard and drill down. [Instructions can be found here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cycles+-+Dependency+Structure+Matrix#Cycles-DependencyStructureMatrix-DependencyStructureMatrix).

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen anything as powerful as Lattix to represent your code in a DSM. While NDepend will generate the DMS it is a static snapshot. Lattix is dynamic allowing the user to change the architecture of the code in the DSM model.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple project, I found [MaDGe - Module Dependency Graph](https://github.com/pahen/madge).

Install with npm

```
npm -g install madge
```

List dependencies of all *.js files in directory `src`

```
madge path/src
```

Find circular dependencies of a particular file `app.js`

```
madge --circular path/src/app.js
```

There's also a graphing functionality, but I don't have that up and running yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you or the companies you work for happen to use ([the non free](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/#edition=commercial)) IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and Java, you can use its [Dependency Structure Matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dsm-tool-window.html).

[image]