# What open source tools could help me understand a large legacy application written in C?

Tags: code-analysis, legacy

I need a tool that I can use to get a better understanding of a large C
project. I'd like to be able to see the relationship between the various C
modules and what calls what, most used functions, what headers are used, etc.

I've searched here and Google but all the source code analysis tools seem to give
you the number of lines of code and other metrics that I'm not interested in. I just
want to get a high level view of how things are structured and interconnected before jumping into the code.

Does anything like this exist?

I've looked at these but they do not seem to do what I want: [Source Code Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)

Since posting this I've tried Doxygen and it seems to give me some of what I need. Any others?

Comment: take a look at this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841552/what-are-the-open-source-alternatives-to-lattix>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [GNU cflow](http://www.gnu.org/s/cflow/), that will analyze the call tree of the functions - you will nicely see the call hierarchy of the functions. Or browse the code with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[Source Navigator](http://sourcenav.berlios.de/) may be helpful for some things (I used it to see call trees). See [screenshots](http://sourcenav.berlios.de/screenshots/).

[cxref](http://www.gedanken.demon.co.uk/cxref/) builds annotated source code cross reference that's easy to view and navigate (I used to create HTML reference of some of my code). See cxref's output on its own source code [here](http://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/cxref/example/cxref.html). Can be used to document the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not OSS, but the tool [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/) can certainly help when it comes to understand a large legacy application written in C or C++.