# TypeScript : Can't reference a static field in a certain context

Tags: class, module, static, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and require.js to resolve dependencies in my files. I'm in a situation where I want to reference a static field of a class in an other class, but in the same internal module (same folder) and I am not able to access it in that specific context. Also, the pre-compiler doesn't show any error in my code, but when accessing the static field at execution, I only get an `undefined` value.

Here are the relevant files :

**Game.ts**
*containing the variable to be accessed*

```
import Scene = require("Scene");
import Stage = require("Stage");

class Game {
    // ...
    static GAME_WIDTH: number = 1920;
    // ...

    public start(): void {
        var currentScene: Scene = new Stage(); // Calls the Stage constructor
    }
}
export = Game;
```

**Launcher.ts**
*entry point of the execution*

```
import Game = require("Game");

console.log(Game.GAME_WIDTH);    // Correctly shows "1920"
var onlyGame: Game = new Game();
onlyGame.start();
```

**Stage.ts**
*in which I'm trying to refer to* `Game.GAME_WIDTH`

```
import Game = require("Game");
import Scene = require("Scene");

class Stage implements Scene {
    constructor() {
        console.log(Game.GAME_WIDTH); // Shows "undefined"
    }
}
export = Stage;
```

`Launcher.ts` will execute first, creating a `Game` instance and starting it, which will create a `Stage` instance that seem to not be able to access `Game.GAME_WIDTH` anymore. I don't understand why I can access the static variable once but can't do it again later in the execution. And the Visual Studio pre-compiler sees nothing wrong in my code.

Can somebody help me with what's wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: **1)** You have the circular dependency problem **2)** module loading order is not defined by the TypeScript language, it is rather left to the module loader and to the script bundler which is unknown in your question **3)** What does the debugger say?

Comment: This comes up reasonably often - there are several ways to avoid the circular dependency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886769/circular-dependency-issue-with-typescript-commonjs-browserify

Comment: **1)** `Game` is dependant of `Stage` even if `Game` has finished its `constructor` (which is empty here) method ?
**2)** I'm using AMD modules with require.js. I'll edit my question.
**3)** The output is too long to be pasted here (and is in french, I'll need to install the English package for convenience when posting them online)

Comment: @Protectator the short answer is that if they are tightly coupled (i.e. they can't live without each other), put them in the same file / module.